# PostGIS raster2pgsql error

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to import raster data into PostGIS using raster2pgsql and as reference the PostGIS Cookbook.

First I created the sql file in the following command

```
raster2pgsql -d -I -C -M -F -t 100x100 -s 4326 tmax*.bil chp01.tmax_2012 > 
tmax_2012.sql
```

When i try to run the sql file using this command line:

```
psql -d postgis_cookbook -U postgres -f tmax_2012.sql
```

I get the following error:

```
LINE 1: ÿþB1F8D1F8D1F8D1F8D1F8D1F8D1F8D1F8D1F8D1F81F8D1F8D1F8D1F8D1F...
```

This also the same when trying only one raster file. I could load the sql file into pgadmin GUI and it works. But i want to do it on the command line

Comment: How about the postgresql log lines related?